# Is it possible to use multiple macros on a single line?

Tags: macros, julia, callstack

Does any know whether it is possible to use multiple macros for a single line? For example,

`@devec, @inbounds [expr]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Yes, you can, since:**](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#macros)

> Macros are the analogue of functions for expression generation at
>   compile time. Just as functions map a tuple of argument values to a
>   return value, macros map a tuple of argument expressions to a returned
>   expression. Macros are invoked with the following general syntax:

```
@name expr1 expr2 ...
@name(expr1, expr2, ...)
```

Here's an example (albeit a slightly nonsensical one) utilizing two well-known macros:

```
# This is an assert construct very similar to what you'd find in a language like
# C, C++, or Python. (This is slightly modified from the example shown in docs)
macro assert(ex)
    return :($ex ? println("Assertion passed") # To show us that `@assert` worked
                 : error("Assertion failed: ", $(string(ex))))
end

# This does exactly what you expect to: time the execution of a piece of code
macro timeit(ex)
    quote
        local t0 = time()
        local val = $ex
        local t1 = time()
        println("elapsed time: ", t1-t0, " seconds")
        val
    end
end
```

However, note these two successful (i.e. - do not throw any errors) macro calls separately:

```
@assert factorial(5)>=0
@timeit factorial(5)
```

And, now together:

```
@timeit @assert factorial(5)>=0
```

Because the right-most macro did not raise an error, the above line returns the total time it took to execute the `factorial(5)` as well as the time to perform the assertion, combined.

However, the important thing to note is that **when one of the macros fail, execution of the other macros in the call stack are of course terminated** (as it should be):

```
# This will throw an error (because we explicitly stated that @assert should
# do so. As such, the rest of the code did not execute.
@timeit @assert factorial(5)<0
```

Again, it's a bit of a silly example, but illustrates the above points and addresses your question.